# Trying to generate a ReadMe using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to generate a ReadMe file using NodeJS and at this moment I am able to create the file but it is only returning [object Object]. I am not able to get the information from the questions I am answering in terminal. Also, I have second file linked to the index.js which should generate the template for the final ReadMe. At the moment I am not sure how to add it to the function to create the template.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const axios = require("axios");
const inquirer = require("inquirer");
const markdown = require("./utils/generateMarkdown");

const questions = [
    {   
        message: "What is the name of the project?",
        name: "title"
    },
    {   
        message: "Please provide a table on content",
        name: "table of content"
    },
    {   
        message: "What is the name of the user?",
        name: "userName"
    },
    {  
        message: "Please provide a description of the project",
        name: "description"
    },
    {   
        message: "What is the installation process?",
        name: "installation"
    },
    {   
        message: "How will this project be used?",
        name: "usage"
    },
    {   
        message: "What licenses are required with this project?",
        name: "licenses"
    },
    {   
        message: "Who were the contributors to this project?",
        name: "contribution"
    },
    {   
        message: "What is the test process for this project?",
        name: "test"
    },
    {   
        message: "What is the user github email address?",
        name: "GitHub user email"
    },
    {   
        message: "Please provide a profile picture",
        name: "GitHub profile picture"
    }
]

function init () {
    inquirer.prompt(questions)
    .then((inquirerResponse, data) => {   
        console.log("Making ReadMe");
        fs.writeFileSync("ReadMe.md", inquirerResponse, data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    })
}

init();

const userName = questions.userName

axios.get(`https://api.github.com/users/${userName}`)
.then(questions => {
  console.log(questions.data);
});
```

Here's the code for the second file.

```
function generateMarkdown(response) {
  return `

# ${response.title}

# Table of Content
-[description](#description)
-[installation](#installation)
-[usage](#usage)
-[licenses](#licenses)
-[contribution](#contribution)
-[test](#test)
-[username](#username)
-[profile](#profile)

${response.username}
##username:

    ${response.description}
##description:

    ${response.installation}
##installation:

    ${response.usage}
##usage:

    ${response.licenses}
##licenses:

    ${response.contribution}
##contribution:

    ${response.test}
##test:

    ${response.email}
##email:

    ${response.profile}
##profile:
`;
}

module.exports = generateMarkdown;
```